Using MFC CDatabase::Open to connect to a SQLite database whose db file name contains non-ASCII characters
My computer program, written in Visual Studio 2022, C++, MFC, x64, uses SQLite as the database to create project files that are similar in concept to how Microsoft Excel creates XLSX files. To maintain database interoperability with other database vendors, we use ODBC, and for SQLite we use the open source ODBC Driver provided by a developer in Switzerland.
Normally, we create SQLite databases (a.k.a. ".db" files) programmatically, meaning no user input is required. However, if the file's file title contains non-ASCII characters (e.g., Cyrillic, East Asian, etc.). Calling CDatabase::Open(...), specifying a connect string with the non-ASCII file name, results in an error. The SQLite3 ODBC Driver Connect dialog box appears, with "???????.db" appearing for the database name. Substituting the desired file name, "Михаил", and hitting OK results in an error message appearing, "connect failed, Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed".
CDatabase Database;

LPCTSTR szConnect = _T("ODBC;DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Database="C:\\Temp\\[Михаил][1].db");// Cyrillic characters

Database.Open(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, szConnect);// Use the old "Open" function, not OpenEx

The SQLite website indicates that the sqlite3_open() API requires UTF-8 encoding of the file name, which would presumably be handled by the ODBC driver, but the CDatabase::Open function expects wide characters.
Note that if I set my computer's Windows region to Russia (Russian), that the exact same code works; it recognizes the Cyrillic characters and connects to the database.
Question - is there a general way to make this connection using CDatabase::Open(...) or other MFC/Win32 API?
